# Why doesn't clicking on my TToolButton show the DropdownMenu?

Tags: delphi

[image]

I'm using Delphi 2010 and I have a TToolButton contained by a TToolBar. Assigned to the 'DropdownMenu' property of my TToolButton is a standard TPopupMenu.

The only way I can get the menu to appear is to click on the area pointed to by the red arrow in the image. Currently, clicking the area pointed to by the green arrow shows the button as pressed, but the dropdown menu does not appear.

What I want is if the user clicks anywhere (pointed to by green arrow or red arrow) for the menu to appear. Is it possible to enable this functionality?

Comment: If you show a button with an attached drop down then the user expects the button to perform the action whose name is the button caption, and that the drop down button drops down the menu. If you drop down for both then you will confuse the user.

Comment: Incidentally Toolbar2000 and TBX have a way to do this (a regular button, with a dropdown arrow, and no split or vertical line).  The lack of a special button type that drops down a menu, but which has no other action (the split between clicking the button and the arrow) is an oversight in the VCL toolbar UI components, in my opinion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea of the `tbsDropDown` style is to have a button that triggers some default action when clicked, but provides more variations of that action in the drop down menu.

If you don't care about the down arrow disappearing, you can set the style to `tbsButton` and no matter where the button is clicked, it will show the popup menu.

If you are like me and you do want to have the arrow there to indicate that there are more options behind this button, you can call [`CheckMenuDropdown`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/ComCtrls.TToolButton.CheckMenuDropdown) in the button's `OnClicked` event handler.

Answer (score 4):

Set `Style` to `tbsButton`. Then you can click anywhere to show the drop-down menu, but you will lose the arrow.